# Option in italics

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

Is there any cross-browser way to italicize `select options`?
With the following CSS and HTML, FireFox shows the second option in italics, but not the third.
None of the options are italicized in IE 7 or Safari.

```
<style>
    option.bravo
    {
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>

<select>
    <option>Alpha</option>
    <option class="bravo">Bravo</option>
    <option><i>Charlie</i></option>
<select>
```

Am I correct in assuming this is not possible?

Comment: You're probably correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This page has a nice chart of browser support of styling select, option and optgroup: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

According to that, the like the only option style that's cross-browser is `color`.

Comment: Readers, be aware that the linked chart hasn't been updated since 2009!

Comment: Have there been updates? Maybe someone should make a new chart!

Answer (score 0):

@MikeWWyatt

I know it's been a while since you asked, but I created this:

1. Wrap  in a paragraph that is position:relative
2. Create a  element that is position absolute
3. Have your option be the same color as your select background color
4. Use jQuery to change the option color to white (or whatever color you want) using .change() as well as hide the

HTML

```
    <p>I am a: <span class='pretend-option'>Please choose one</span>

    <select name="example">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please choose one</option>
        <option value="consumer">Consumer</option>
        <option value="supplier">Supplier</option>
        <option value="retailer">Retailer</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
     $('select').change(function () { 
          $(this).css('color', 'white'); 
          $(this).parent('p').children('.pretend-option').css('z-index', -1); 
    });
```

CSS

```
    select, option {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    p {
        position: relative;
    }
    select {
        padding: 7px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: blue;
    }
   .pretend-option {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.5em;
        color: #fff;
        left: 0.5em;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 1;
        font-style: italic;
}
```

Here's a fiddle if you're interested: https://jsfiddle.net/ej34bea0/